# create constraint from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My WebPage on provider and database mysql on remote server

I try create constraint on my table from my web page , i get always error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 REFERENCES
>   command denied to user 'root'@'infong315.kundenserver.de' for table
>   'personnel' ;

root permission from all ip ;

any idea?

Comment: You don't have permissions to do that OR your have a syntax-Error. Too less informations to give you an answer. Anyway it is a bad idea to allow remote access on a database server.

Comment: my query  work correctly from local or from remote over any software like navicat and this problem formed after mysql upgraded from 5.6.36 to 5.7.18

Comment: My Query :ALTER TABLE model_ims.personnel_professional_training ADD CONSTRAINT personnel_id_ibfk FOREIGN KEY (personnel_id) REFERENCES personnel(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your user has the privileges to perform the action you are trying to do. In your case you need to run this:

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON database_name.personnel TO root@'infong315.kundenserver.de'
```

Change "database_name" to the name of your database

Comment: i have it tried already but after command run on local with navicat , 
get error
"Can't find any matching row in the user table"

run only query GRANT REFERENCES ON model_ims.personnel
 TO root@'%'; but this already created!

Comment: That sounds like your root user doesn't exist. Can you confirm that it does?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I have choosed Database as information_schema, have replaced to target database name, now it working.
Thanks for your help!